# read integers and return number of inputs satisfying certain condition

Tags: haskell

Im trying to write a little program in haskell that takes integers as inputs until a certain condition, say P, is fulfilled and then prints out the number of all elements which fulfill a condition Q. My code is the following

```
list = []
main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- getLine
    read x : list
    if (P) then putStrLine "length (filter Q list)" else main
```

But im getting the error „illegal escape sequence“. Could somebody give some advice how to solve this? I guess the problem is that i can’t recursively call the main function?
thanks in advance.

Comment: I honestly don't know where this error will come from - right now the obvious error is the `if (P)` and of course `read x : list` do nothing - also do you expect the string `"length (filter Q list)" to somehow evaluate to something?

Comment: overall there are many issues in this small snippet and I would suggest you split this question into several parts or brush up your basics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is what I can take away from your description:

```
readIn :: (Integer -> Bool) -> IO [Integer]
readIn stop = do
  i <- read <$> getLine
  if stop i then return [] else do
    rest <- readIn stop
    return (i:rest)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  xs <- readIn (> 10)
  print (length (filter even xs))
```

as you can see I refactored out the *reading* of the input list (note that I did not handle bad-formatted input like `"noNumber"` - it will only work if you input something that can be `read` into `Integer`) with `readIn`

The first argument to `readIn` is just your `P` - as an example I used `(> 10)` so it will stop asking for more if you enter a number bigger than `10`.

the rest is just using `List.filter` together with `length` to get your "number of all elements wich fulfill a condition" - I used `even` as an example for such

#### example run

```
λ> :main
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
4 -- this is the result
```